# Solidity: Retrieving values of Array of Structs in Mapping

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I have some solidity code where I am attempting to gather the ids which are a value stored on a Struct.  I have a mapping where the key is an address, and the value is an array of Structs. Whenever I execute the `getMediaByAddress` function I get an `invalid OpCode error`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract MediaGallery {
address owner;
uint counter;

struct MediaAsset {
    uint id;
    string name;
    address author;
    uint createDate;
    string[] tags;
    string mediaHash;
}

mapping(address => MediaAsset[]) public mediaDatabase;

constructor () {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function addMedia(string _name, string _mediaHash) public returns (bool success) {
    MediaAsset memory currentMedia;

    currentMedia.id = counter;
    currentMedia.name = _name;
    currentMedia.author = msg.sender;
    currentMedia.createDate = now;
    currentMedia.mediaHash = _mediaHash;

    mediaDatabase[msg.sender].push(currentMedia);

    return true;
}

function addTag(uint _id, string _tag) public returns (bool success) {
    mediaDatabase[msg.sender][_id].tags.push(_tag);

    return true;
}

function getMediaByAddress(address _user) public view returns (uint[]) {
    uint[] memory mediaAssetIds = new uint[](mediaDatabase[_user].length);

    uint numberOfMediaAssets = 0;

    for(uint i = 1; i <= mediaDatabase[_user].length;  i++) {
        mediaAssetIds[numberOfMediaAssets] = mediaDatabase[_user][i].id;
        numberOfMediaAssets++;
    }
    return mediaAssetIds;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to read past the end of the array. Your loop variable `i` has an off-by-one error. Its greatest value is `mediaDatabase[_user].length`, which is 1 past the end of the array. Try this instead:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < mediaDatabase[_user].length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I tried adjusting though, and I still receive, `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode`

Comment: Your contract seems to work fine for me in Remix. I deployed, called `addMedia` twice, and then I called `getMediaByAddress`, passing the address I used to call `addMedia`. I got back `0, 0`. (`counter` is never incremented, so all `MediaAsset`s have an `id` of `0`.) If you're still having trouble, please provide full repro steps.

Comment: I should say it works fine after my fix to the `for` loop.

Comment: Yep. I failed to re-compile. :-)